# Noun subject followed directly by a V-ing in the where clause without "be"

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds, continuous-aspect, whiz-deletion, present-continuous

On the Wikipedia page for "Team error", I found this text:

> Halo Effect – Immediate judgment discrepancy or cognitive bias, where a person making an initial assessment will assume the validity of ambiguous information based upon concrete information: blind trust in the competence of specific individuals because of their experience or education.

*Source*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_error

In that, the noun (also the subject of the *where* clause, I guess) **a person** is directly followed by a V-ing **making**. But this is not usual to my eye where I often see an infinitive verb or be + V-ing in stead of a V-ing, so it could have been:

> ... where a person makes an initial assessment...

Or:

> ... where a person is making an initial assessment...

So my question is: is that type of grammar construction valid?

Comment: Yes, it's valid. Your first suggestion won't work because "a person" is head of a noun phrase functioning as subject of the "will" verb phrase. "Making an initial  ..." is a gerund-participial clause modifying "person". It has the same meaning as the relative clause in "a person [who makes an initial ...]".

Comment: Thanks @BillJ, I believe the question is now answered.